# How to make Vertical spacing B/W UIFields using Auto-layouts in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

[image]

Hi I am very new for iOS and in my app I am using Auto-layouts Visual format

But how can I change vertical spacing at various conditions

For this I used below code but vertical spacing is not setting b/w UIfields

see my below screen vertical space I have given here "15" but it's not applying

### my code:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 NSDictionary * views1 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(RoundTripLabel,RoundTripDateTextField,RoundTripButton,BottomLabel1,BottomLabel2);


//Appying Horizental contstraints:-

    [MainScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-8-[RoundTripLabel]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views1]];

    [MainScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-8-[RoundTripDateTextField]-8-[RoundTripButton(30)]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views1]];

    [MainScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-8-[BottomLabel1]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views1]];

    [MainScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-8-[BottomLabel2]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views1]];


    //Appying Vertical contstraints:-

    [MainScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[RoundTripLabel(17)]-10-[RoundTripDateTextField]-0-[BottomLabel1(17)]-10-[BottomLabel2(17)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views1]];

     NSDictionary * views2 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(RoundTripLabel,RoundTripButton);

    [MainScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[RoundTripLabel]-10-[RoundTripButton]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views2]];


    //Defining  Heights Using Constraint With Item Formate:-

    RoundTripDateTextFieldHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:RoundTripDateTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
    [MainScrollView addConstraint:RoundTripDateTextFieldHeight];

    RoundTripButtonHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:RoundTripButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
    [MainScrollView addConstraint:RoundTripButtonHeight];

    VerticalSpacing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:BottomLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:RoundTripDateTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:15.0f];
    [MainScrollView addConstraint:RoundTripDateTextFieldHeight];

    [MainScrollView setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Comment: how can i use this i want to set Vertical spacing dynamically that what my intention

Comment: i mean u see my above screen shot there i want to give vertical space b/w "BottomLabel1" and UItextfield(dark gray color textfield) dynamically

Comment: i mean some situactions it may 100 or some situation it may 50 ...etc

Comment: if u don't mind can i send my sample x code file please see once it's very oregent

Comment: yes ur right let me send my project file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05NQoG9RAmwbGR5azM3MkFHUGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this is project file please check once

Comment: hi @EI Captain u checking?

Comment: ok ok please checking

Comment: which coment do i have to delete bro...?

Comment: did u modified that code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104400/discussion-between-ei-captain-and-abhiram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, there is problem with these constraints

**1st contsraint:**

instead of adding `RoundTripDateTextFieldHeight` again, you need to add `VerticalSpacing`

```
VerticalSpacing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:BottomLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:RoundTripDateTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:15.0f];
[MainScrollView addConstraint:VerticalSpacing];  // instead of [MainScrollView addConstraint:RoundTripDateTextFieldHeight];
```

**2nd**

add vertical spacing between 2 labels

```
NSLayoutConstraint *VerticalSpacingLbl2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:BottomLabel2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:BottomLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
[MainScrollView addConstraint:VerticalSpacingLbl2];
```

**3rd**

change below constraint

```
  //Appying Vertical contstraints:-

  [MainScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[RoundTripLabel(17)]-10-[RoundTripDateTextField]-0-[BottomLabel1(17)]-10-[BottomLabel2(17)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views1]];
```

with this

```
 [MainScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[RoundTripLabel(17)]-10-[RoundTripDateTextField]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views1]];
```